# Xml to Object in Swift on SOAP webservice

Tags: ios, xml, swift, serialization, deserialization

I'm using a web service, by calling a web method I want to retrieve data into multiple objects, but I get a string of an xml so I want to deserialize it.

Now I'm using a parser to retrieve each values, but I need to use objects.

Xml Parser:

```
var elementValue: String?
var elementSuccess: String?
var elementContactWebId: String?
var contactWebId = ""
var success = ""

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser,didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {
    if elementName == "code" {
        elementSuccess = String()
    }
    if elementName == "contactWebID" {
        elementContactWebId = String()
    }
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
    if elementSuccess != nil {
        elementSuccess! += string
    }
    if elementContactWebId != nil {
        elementContactWebId! += string
    }
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
    if elementName == "code" {
        success = elementSuccess!
    }
    if elementName == "contactWebID" {
        contactWebId = elementContactWebId!
    }
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, parseErrorOccurred parseError: NSError) {
    print("parseErrorOccurred: \(parseError)")
}
```

How I call the web service (not full, xml in strData):

```
 let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

            let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(theRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
                print("Response Login: \(response)")
                let strData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
                print("Body Login: \(strData)")
                if error != nil
                {
                    print("Error Login: " + error!.description)
                }
                let parser = NSXMLParser(data: data!)
                parser.delegate = self
                parser.parse()
                if(self.success == "1"){
                    self.successSoap = 1
                } else {
                    self.successSoap = 0
                }
                self.contactWebID = Int(self.contactWebId)!
                completion(result: self.successSoap, resultContactWebId: Int(self.contactWebId)!)
            })
```

One of my object:

```
class SendLeadReponse: Reponse {
    var option: SendLeadOption


    init(code: Int, message: String, option: SendLeadOption){
        self.option = option
        super.init(code: code, message: message)
    }


}
```